# What's the difference between './' and '../' when using os.path.isdir()?

Tags: python, os.path

I'm new to python. And something is confusing me today. Under the path `c:\python\`, there are several folds. I edit a python script under this path, and run the code:

```
for dir_name in os.listdir("./"):
        print dir_name
        print os.path.isdir(dir_name)
```

It prints:

```
Daily
True
renafile.py
False
script
True
```

But when I put the script in fold `Daily` which is under the path `C:\python\`,and run code:

```
for dir_name in os.listdir("../"):
        print dir_name
        print os.path.isdir(dir_name)
```

It prints:

```
Daily
False
renafile.py
False
script
False
```

Did they have the difference?

Comment: Note: I'm using python2.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was returning false because when you call isdir with a folder name, python looks for that folder in the current directory - unless you provide an absolute path or a relative path.

Since you are listing files in `"../"`, you should call isdir like so:

```
print os.path.isdir(os.path.join("../", dir_name))
```

You may want to modify your code to:

```
list_dir_name = "../"
for dir_name in os.listdir(list_dir_name):
  print dir_name
  print os.path.isdir(os.path.join(list_dir_name, dir_name))
```

Comment: I would recommend using `os.path.join` instead of just `+`.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil good call, I changed the snippet :) L.Bes, glad I could help :)

Comment: Anish Goyal - Sorry, I click solved just now and it notice 'in 5 minutes'

Comment: It's fine haha, I probably shouldn't have mentioned it. Thank you though

Comment: Haha, I did that before you mentioned it.  Anyway, this is my first question on stackoverflow. Thank you!